# How to use MathJax in a form?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, mathjax

I have a textbox in a form and I want to use MathJax.I have downloaded it, but don't know how to use it.
I am using ASP-MVC3.
Thanks for your helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue.Its just needed to load js files from mathjax.org and add these lines to the `head` tag.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        MathJax.Hub.Config({ TeX: { equationNumbers: { autoNumber: "all" } } });
    });
</script>
<script src="~/Scripts/MathJax.js?config=Tex-AMS_HTML"></script>
```

And now its just needed to add the characters `$$` and `\\` to the text in the following form and append it to something like a div.

```
jQuery("#radikal").on('click', function () {
    var x="$$\\sqrt[3]{8}$$";
    $("#formul").append(x);
});

<input type="button" id="radikal"/>
<div id="formul"></div>
```

And now we will have a radical in `div#radikal`.
Thats all.